# WPF Register application level event / class

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, barcode-scanner, event-sourcing

I am currently developing an app, which should supports handheld scanner. The problem I have is how to actually register my scan event globally within an app?

I have tried to place my code in `App.xaml.cs` (as naively I thought that this would be a place where I can register application level hooks) but the event seems to not fire.

I suppose the problem is, that I am using **Prism** with **Unity**, which means that I have a single window application, where only one View at a time can be displayed (together with its corresponding ViewModel) which (probably) causes that my event is being lost somewhere.

When I create simple application with no routing (e.g. simple WinForm app) and register my event, I get result every time with no problem.

Here is what my register event handler looks like:

```
cCoreScannerClass.BarcodeEvent += new _ICoreScannerEvents_BarcodeEventEventHandler(OnBarcodeEvent);
```

with corresponding:

```
    public void OnBarcodeEvent(short eventType, ref string pscanData)
    {
        var result = pscanData; //< this is scanned barcode result I need to publish
    }
```

I have also tried to create a simple class which in constructor registers this event, plus registered it under `Bootstrapper.cs` class with `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()`, but the event was for uknown to me reason not firing.

Any help in respect to this matter would be highly appreciated as frankly said, I don't quite know how to go forward with this.

**Edit:**
I have managed to get it working by instantiating the scanner class under `Bootstrapper.cs` under `InitializeShell()` method. Is this approach correct or is it breaking any best practices rules?

Answer (score 0):

The general pattern for this in WPF is to use the Messenger pattern. The VM that get's the original event will post an application specific message to the messenger and it will be propagated to any VM that subscribed to it. It's a very simple pattern and keeps the VMs from knowing about each other. I wouldn't put VM code in the app class. That's bad practice. The app class is for stuff related to the application behavior such as start up, shut down, etc. Not for handling shared views.

Comment: As I have mentioned in the comment, I have in the end instantiated my code under Bootstrapper.cs class, where into my `Scanner.cs` I am also injecting `IEventAggregator` which if I am not mistaken is following the Messenger pattern, doesn't it?